# How to access files stored in the hard disk using SageMath/Jupyter running on Virtual Machine

Tags: python, virtual-machine, virtualbox, jupyter, sage

Is it possible to access a file stored in my hard disk from SageMath/Jupyter running on VirtualBox?

Answer (score 2):

Just worked out a solution (pretty obvious): a shared folder as to be defined in VirtualBox with the "auto-mount" option ticked. Then the 'upload' button in Jupyter can be used.